# 'raml2html' is not recognized though installed via npm i -g raml2html: Windows

Tags: rest, npm, yaml, raml

I was trying to run raml2html to convert some contracts to HTML, this was working initially when first time I did the installation on my Windows machine but after some weeks when I tired running this again then this command stopped working. Not sure what happened.

What I again tired installing raml2html by running `npm i -g raml2html` but still its saying:

```
'raml2html' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I again tried uninstalling and reinstalling also but still the same issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to find where the installation is creating the command line script for Windows (a file ending `.cmd`). That can be found opening a Powershell terminal and using the `where` command. It usually is under the `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` directory.

Comment: Hi Aled, i added the screenshots above, i did not find any cmd file here.

Comment: What's in the bin subdirectory?

Comment: raml2html file only. screenshot attached above

Comment: It looks like NPM didn't create the CMD for Windows. Maybe an NPM issue?

Comment: but how the earlier one got deleted , if it existed, it looks strange? as it was working fine earlier.

Comment: Maybe some antivirus/security in your computer o NPM issue.